# Does $\frac{n(A+B)}{2}+\frac{m(C+D)}{2}=1+\frac{nB+mD}{nA+mC}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Does the following equality hold: $$\frac{n(A+B)}{2}+\frac{m(C+D)}{2}=1+\frac{nB+mD}{nA+mC}?$$ This seems to be implied in the given solution to a course problem I'm working on, but I can't follow the reasoning. (I'm hoping this is just a fraction-manipulation problem; including the context would make the question considerably longer.)

Comment: For $n=D=0$ and $m=C=1$ the LHS is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ but the RHS is equal to 1.

Comment: @Keine_Maschine Right. I guess the context matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason this equality should hold. To see this, just let $n = 0$ and let $A,B,C,D,m = 1$. Then we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{n(A + B)}{2} + \frac{m(C + D)}{2} &= 1 + \frac{nB + mD}{nA + mC}\\
\frac{0(1 + 1)}{2} + \frac{1(1 + 1)}{2} &= 1 + \frac{0\cdot 1 + 1\cdot 1}{0\cdot 1 + 1\cdot 1}\\
\frac{1(2)}{2} &= 1 + \frac{1}{1}\\
1 &= 1 + 1\\
1 &= 2,
\end{align}
which is obviously not true.